# Find text field value on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have to find the value of `qty` when I click on the plus or minus icon. This is my code:

```
<div class='col-md-2 col-xs-2'>
  <img src='<?=base_url()?>assets/img/Plus.png' class='img-responsive carticons pull-right '>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6">
  <div class="form-group" style="padding-top: 5px;">
    <input type="number" value="<?=$qty?>" class="qty pull-right" min="<?=$qty?> "name="qty">
  </div>
  <div class='col-md-2 col-xs-2' style='padding-left:0; '>
    <img src='<?=base_url()?>assets/img/Minus.png' class='img-responsive carticons pull-left'>
  </div>
  <input type='hidden' data-qty='<?=$qty;?>' class='minqty' value='<?=$value->qty;?>' />
```

```js
$('.carticons').on('click',function(){
  var quantity = $(this).find('input[name=qty]').val();
  alert(quantity);
})
```

In the `alert()` it gives me `undefined`. How can I fix this?

Comment: add space b/w `min="<?=$qty?> "name="qty"` min and name attr

Comment: .find check all element which descends from the object, which in your case is a image, and it won't work, 
use $('.qty' ).val() instead

Answer (score 0):

Use `$(this).parent().prev(".form-group").find('input[name=qty]').val()`
 Or `$(this).closest(".col-md-4).find('input[name=qty]').val()`

```js
$('.carticons').on('click', function() {
  var quantity = $(this).parent().prev(".form-group").find('input[name=qty]').val();
  alert(quantity);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='col-md-2 col-xs-2'>
  <img src='<?=base_url()?>assets/img/Plus.png' class='img-responsive carticons pull-right '>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6">
  <div class="form-group" style="padding-top: 5px;">
    <input type="number" value="<?=$qty?>" class="qty pull-right" min="" name="qty">

  </div>
  <div class='col-md-2 col-xs-2' style='padding-left:0; '>
    <img src='<?=base_url()?>assets/img/Minus.png' class='img-responsive carticons pull-left' alt="img">
  </div>
  <input type='hidden' data-qty='<?=$qty;?>' class='minqty' value='<?=$value->qty;?>' />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you'd only have one input with the name 'qty', you need only get rid of the find and reference the element directly.

`find()` is going to search through the descendants of the element and match on the provided selector, in your case the `img` that was clicked, which has no descendants.

```js
$('.carticons').on('click',function(){
    var quantity = $('input[name=qty]').val();
    alert(quantity);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='col-md-2 col-xs-2'>
   <img src='http://placehold.it/50x50' class='img-responsive carticons pull-right '>
   </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6">
      <div class="form-group" style="padding-top: 5px;">
     <input type="number" value="<?=$qty?>" class="qty pull-right" min="<?=$qty?> "name="qty" >

</div>
<div class='col-md-2 col-xs-2' style='padding-left:0; '>
  <img src='<?=base_url()?>assets/img/Minus.png' class='img-responsive carticons pull-left'>
   </div>
   <input type='hidden' data-qty='<?=$qty;?>' class='minqty' value='<?=$value->qty;?>' />
```

Comment: Sure but do they all have unique "names"?  The selector you're using to target the input will only target those with `name='qty'`.  `name` should be unqiue to your form anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class='col-md-2 col-xs-2'>
  <img src='<?=base_url()?>assets/img/Plus.png' class='img-responsive carticons pull-right '>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6">
  <div class="form-group" style="padding-top: 5px;">
    <input type="number" value="<?=$qty?>" class="qty pull-right" min="<?=$qty?> "name="qty">
  </div>
  <div class='col-md-2 col-xs-2' style='padding-left:0; '>
    <img src='<?=base_url()?>assets/img/Minus.png' class='img-responsive carticons pull-left'>
  </div>
  <input type='hidden' data-qty='<?=$qty;?>' class='minqty' value='<?=$value->qty;?>' />
</div>




<script>
  $(document).on('click','.carticons',function()
    {
      var quantity = $(document).find('input[name="qty"]').val();
      alert(quantity);
    })
</script>
```

Instead of `$(this)` you can use `$(document)`